# How to grab a single image from RTSP stream using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have seen several other related questions but they all seem to be related to grabbing a still shot every X number of seconds. How can I grab 1 image when the command is run.

I was trying

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.113:554/live -f image2 -updatefirst 1 do.jpg
```

Comment: Why the `-f image2 -updatefirst 1`. You only want one output.

Comment: when I run it without I get `[image2 @ 0x2886980] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'do.jpg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
`

Answer (score 37):

Try

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.113:554/live -vframes 1 do.jpg
```

Comment: i've used this command for a while, but about 20% of the time I get a corrupted frame

Comment: RTSP, if via UDP, can drop packets. Try TCP.

Comment: For those wondering, to use TCP with the above command add:  `-rtsp_transport tcp`

Comment: For those who struggled over this as much as I did, 2 pro tips: `-rtsp_transport tcp` option must be placed *before* `-i ...`option, and `-vframes` is an now an obsolete alias for `-frames:v` (use the latter instead of the former)

Comment: While this works on my Mac, it hangs on windows after listing the library names ending with libpostproc

Answer (score 2):

I've been using variations to use my Ubiquiti cameras to give me a Weather Underground JPG.

The tcp transport addition fixed everything. The modified command follows.

```
E $FFMPEG -y -loglevel fatal -rtsp_transport tcp -i $URL1 -frames:v 2 -r 1 -s 320x240 $TMPFILE
```

Comment: Why 2 in `-frames:v 2`? Does that help reduce corruption? I get less but still some corruption with tcp.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this command, but its not perfect, about 20% of the time I get a corrupted (as in incomplete, or glitchy) image over a bad link:

```
avconv -rtsp_transport tcp -y -i rtsp://user:pass@192.168.0.1:554/live -vframes 1 do.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need download [ffmpeg.exe](https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/releases) file to your computer and unzip,
Secondly, open Windows Terminal or PowerShell or CMD in your unzipped path and enter the bin directory,enter the following command:

```
.\ffmpeg -i rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.1:554/media/video0 -ss 1 -f image2 C:\Users\Desktop\1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a "proxy" app like https://github.com/gallofeliz/snapshot-proxy-cam that handle fallbacks and centralize your cams